# disable strange comment behavior in AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, comment

When I have a commented line in my TeX file, eg

```
some text that is not commented
|%% here is a comment
followed by more uncommented text
```

(the | represents point), and I hit `RET`, point is moved past the `%%` and into the comment, like so:

```
some text that is not commented

%% |here is a comment
followed by more uncommented text
```

This seems very strange, and to me it is undesirable. For instance, if I want to add another newline before the commented line, I have to backtrack to the beginning of the line first. I want point to stay in front of the `%` characters.

How can I disable this annoying behavior?

Comment: That is odd. I'm not sure how to fix it, but in the meantime the command `C-o` will open a new line at point, which does what you want `RET` to do in this case.

Comment: I know about `C-o` (which calls the function `open-line`), but that leaves point on the current line, that is, it inserts the newline after point, not before it. I just want `RET` to act like it used to and I don't understand why this behavior is now the default. It is truly bizarre.

Comment: Do you use additional minor modes or packages which might hook into the key bindings and alter them?  To me, it seems that another package has simply altered the way comments are handled, by enforcing that the pointer is moved behind the comment prefix.

Comment: What is the value of the variable `electric-indent-mode` in your .tex file where you observe this?  If `t`, please try `M-x electric-indent-local-mode RET` and try it again.

Comment: `(setq LaTeX-syntactic-comments nil)` solved it for me (see this [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Indenting.html)).

Comment: @ArchStanton That fixed it! Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `(setq LaTeX-syntactic-comments nil)` to your `init.el` to disable the option `LaTeX-syntactic-comments`.

According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Indenting.html):

> User Option: LaTeX-syntactic-comments
>   If non-nil comments will be filled and indented according to LaTeX syntax. Otherwise they will be filled like normal text.